# How to animate cloned element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

What i want to do is looped horizontaly text slider.
My attempt - when end of text is displayed, clone this element move to right end and play animation for cloned element again - but i can't achieve that because for some reason cloned element don't want to animate.

*This is chrome only app*

**Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLw9k54f/1/).**

CSS

```
#elm {
  width: 100px;
  height:20px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}

#elm::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important; }
#elm .inner-elm {
  position:absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="elm">
  <div class="inner-elm"> 11111111 2222222 333333 4444444</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var elm_right = $('#elm').offset().left + $('#elm').outerWidth();

var settings = {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() {
      var this_right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();

       // make some clone
      if(!$(this).hasClass('cloned') && ((this_right + 50) < elm_right)) {
        $(this).addClass('cloned');

        var clone = $(this).clone(true);
        clone.addClass('cloned')
          .css('left', $('#elm').width())
          .appendTo('#elm')
          .animate({right:100}, settings);
      }


      // remove parent
      if( (this_right - 20) < $('#elm').offset().left) {
        $(this).remove();
      }

  }
};

var that = $('#elm .inner-elm');
that.animate({right: that.outerWidth()}, settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 transitions for a simple animation like this. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nLw9k54f/5/)

```js
var interval = 2000;
var nextTimeout = 200;
var wrapper = $('#elm');
var elem = $('.inner-elm', wrapper);
elem.addClass('move');

setInterval(function(){
  var clone = elem.clone(true);
  elem.remove();
  elem = clone;
  elem.removeClass('move');
  wrapper.append(elem);
  setTimeout(function(){
   elem.addClass('move');
  }, nextTimeout);
}, interval);
```

```css
#elm {
  height:20px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}

.inner-elm{
    transition: all 2s linear;
    -ms-transform: translate(110%, 0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(110%x, 0); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(110%, 0);
}

.move{
    -ms-transform: translate(-130%, 0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-130%, 0); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(-130%, 0);
}

#elm::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important; height: 0 !important; }
#elm .inner-elm {
  position:relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elm">
  <div class="inner-elm">Stackoverflow</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This not work for my case - i want text will be cloned, nearly after the end is displayed, in your example it must be full hidden to show again. I also want to know why cloned element can't play animation like normal DOM does. But thanks for your answer!